# CodeIgniter, Can´t call function of library class "Template"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter framework.
The problem I have is that I can't call not a single function of a library class file. Here is the code:

This is the library file called Template:

```
<?php      
    class Template 
    {
        var $template_data = array();
        public function __construct()   {
            $this-> CI =& get_instance();
        }

        public function load($template, $view, $view_data = array()){
            $this->set('content', $this->CI->load->view($view, $view_data, TRUE));
            return $this->CI->load->view($template, $this->template_data);
        }
    }

    function hallo() {
        echo "Hallo";
    }

    function set($key, $value) {
        $template_data[$key] = $value;
    }

?>
```

This is the Controller called "Pages":

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    function view($page) {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))  {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->library('template');

        $this->template->set('hallo', 'My Navigation');
        $template->set('adress', 'My Adress');
        $template->set('tel', '007');
        $template->load('basic_template', 'Pages/'. $page, $data);
        $template->hallo();

    }

}

?>
```

As you can maybe see I am loading the template of the library directory. Then I want to use the "set" method and the "hallo" method, but it does not seem to work. This is the error message:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Template::set()

Filename: \CodeIgniter\application\controllers\Pages.php

Line Number: 16

Backtrace:

File: \CodeIgniter\index.php
Line: 308
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New template file is
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoGwFZPrusejW_V_mS_2oSyDw-gHRAPc/view?usp=sharing

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class Template 

        {

            var $ci;
            function __construct() 
            {

                $this->ci = &get_instance();

            }

            function load($tpl_view, $body_view = null, $data = null) 
            {
                if ( ! is_null( $body_view ) ) 

                {
                    if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$tpl_view.'/'.$body_view ) ) 
                    {
                        $body_view_path = $tpl_view.'/'.$body_view;
                    }
                    else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$tpl_view.'/'.$body_view.'.php' ) ) 
                        {
                            $body_view_path = $tpl_view.'/'.$body_view.'.php';
                        }

                        else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$body_view ) ) 

                            {
                                $body_view_path = $body_view;
                            }

                            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$body_view.'.php' ) ) 

                                {
                                    $body_view_path = $body_view.'.php';
                                }

                                else

                                {
                                    show_error('Unable to load the requested file: ' . $tpl_name.'/'.$view_name.'.php');
                                }



                    $body = $this->ci->load->view($body_view_path, $data, TRUE);

                    if ( is_null($data) ) 

                    {
                        $data = array('body' => $body);
                    }
                    else if ( is_array($data) )

                        {
                            $data['body'] = $body;
                        }

                    else if ( is_object($data) )

                       {
                                $data->body = $body;
                       }

                }
                $this->ci->load->view('templates/'.$tpl_view, $data);
            }
        }?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Omg you created for me the whole file. I would hug you, but I guess its impossible to do that. You are a real lifesaver. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 mistakes in your code

the first one is your template class, where you need to end the class with a `}` bracket. Your finishing bracket is before the 2 last functions. The correct structure sould be:

```
class Template{

        public function load()
        {
        }
        public function hello()
        {
        }
        public function set()
        {
        }
}
```

the 2nd mistake (which will show up, once you fixed the 1st issue) is to use $template in the hope this will call the class Template. It will give the error: `Undefined variable: template`

in order to use $template to call the class you need to define:

```
$template=$this->template;
```

then you can:

```
$template->set('adress', 'My Adress');
```